# Intento iniciar sesion en una pagina con requests y python, pero no puedo

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

estoy intentando hacer un bot que inicie sesion en zalando.fr, no quiero usar selenium, solo quiere usar requests, intente buscando la post request con mis credenciales cuando se incia sesion, pero no logre encontrarla, asi que ahora estoy intentando iniciar sesion con las cookies, por lo que tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
from requests import Session
from requests.utils import cookiejar_from_dict
from codecs import open

def main():
    cookies = '''cookie en texto plano que consegui al hacer un document.cookie despues del login en la pagina web'''
    s = Session()
    cookie_dict = {}
    for cookie in cookies.split(";"):
        cookie =  cookie.split("=")
        cookie_dict[cookie[0]] = cookie[1]
    cj = cookiejar_from_dict(cookie_dict)
    print("Cookie jar to dict done...")
    s.cookies = cj
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }
    print("Requesting")
    html = s.get("https://www.zalando.fr/myaccount/", headers=headers)
    print("request done")

    html = s.get("https://www.zalando.fr/myaccount/", headers=headers)
    print("request done")
    if "Mi nombre" in html.text:
        print('Good')
     else:
        print("Bad")
    with open("response.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html.text) 
    s.close()



 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

El codigo basicamente inicia una sesion, pone mis cookies, y va a una parte de la pagina para la que necesitas estar loggeado, despues checa si en la respuesta esta mi nombre (porque la pagina dice "bonjour usuario" cuando inicias sesion) despues guarda la respuesta en un documento html, y cuando lo abro es la pagina de login.

Como puedo iniciar sesion en esta pagina web? Estoy haciendo algo mal con las cookies?
Aprecio mucho cualquier consejo, gracias.

Comment: Hola! Y por qué no puedes, ¿algún error?, ¿Qué es exactamente lo que sucede?

Comment: @RubialesAlberto No hay ningun error que se imprima en pantalla, solo no inicia sesion. Cuando se escribe en archivo response.html sale el portal de inicio de sesion en lugar de la pagina de bienvenida.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente, directo de la [documentación](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies):

```
cookies = dict(cookie_name=cookie_value)
response = requests.get("https://www.zalando.fr/myaccount/", cookies=cookies)
```